# Is "If I die one day, at least I lived." grammatical?

Tags: present-perfect, conditional-constructions

Is “If I die one day, at least I lived.” grammatical?

I am not sure if it's correct or should I use *"I have lived*"?

Comment: I feel the word “if” makes this a fairly odd/questionable statement altogether (though it may admittedly be warranted by some context) but, strictly speaking, I see no grammatical problems.

Comment: We will all die "one day", so those two words are redundant.

Comment: I would have thought a version with _have_ would be preferable.

Comment: If I die one day, I don't care about grammer mistakes anymore.

Answer (score 2):

As Chris says, "the word “if” makes this a fairly odd/questionable statement altogether (though it may admittedly be warranted by some context) but, strictly speaking, I see no grammatical problems."

The version with "have lived" would be preferable (this is a normal context for present perfect meaning "a state starting in the past and continuing to the present")

The words "one day" are a little odd in this context, as the conditional  "If I die one day" is always true.  Perhaps you mean "today"  or "Even though I'll die one day".

---

Note that it's pragmatically *essential* for the intended meaning that the verb following ***at least*** should be *emphatic*. In speech, this could be achieved by placing heavy stress on the word ***lived***, but in practice it would normally be reflected by using a "past in the future" verb form, which forces the audience/reader to focus on that future time (*after* the speaker has died)...

> *...at least I **will have** lived*

Comment: CW for summarising the answers given in comments

Comment: What does "CW" mean?

Answer (score 0):

I'd argue there's a tonal difference between *at least I lived* and *at least I have lived* - the former places the "living" in the past, gives the sense of past experiences, and gives it more of a bittersweet feel than "I have lived" (which puts less distance between the speaker and those experiences).

It can also be read as "dying is bad, but being unlucky enough to face death means you were lucky enough to be given life". I think throwing *have* in there makes it less ambiguous and drags it towards the first meaning of "I have done some things in my life" and not "I existed". As it is, it's open-ended and poetic, a little philosophical, and extremely snappy. It's good!